# Elasticsearch: Is it possible to index fields not present in source?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to make Elasticsearch index fields that are not present in the source document? An example of what I want to do is to index a [Geo Point](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-point-type.html), but not store the value and to leave it out of the `_source` field. Then I could do searches and aggregations based on location, geohash etc., but not return the position in the result documents themselves, e.g., for privacy reasons.

The possibility seems to not be too far fetched, since mappings can cause fields in the source to be indexed in several different ways, for instance the Geo Point type can index `pos.lon`, `pos.lat` and `pos.geohash` even though these are not in the original source document.

I have looked at [source filtering](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html), but that seems to only apply to searches and not indexing. I did not find a way to use it in aliases.

The only way I've found to accomplish something like this would be to not store `_source`, but do store all other fields, except the single one I want to hide. That seems overly clumsy though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with mappings:

In my index creation code, I have the following:

```
        "mappings" : {
            "item" : {
                "_source" : {"excludes" : ["uploader"]},
                "properties" : { ... }
            }
        },
        "settings" : { ... }
```

('item' is the document type of my index.  'uploader' in this case is an email address - something we want to search by, but don't want to leak to the user.)

Then I just include 'uploader' as usual when indexing source documents.  I can search by it, but it's not returned in any results.

My related question: [How to create elasticsearch index alias that excludes specific fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349705/how-to-create-elasticsearch-index-alias-that-excludes-specific-fields) - not quite the same :)